# Absolute positioned div not hidden

Tags: html, overflow, positioning

I have this

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="div1"></div>
<div>
```

Now, let's assume that:

- the "container" has a width of 300px
- the "container" has overflow: hidden;
- the "div1" has a width of 1000px;
- the "div1" is absolute positioned, top:0px,left:0px;

The problem:

The "div1" is not hidden, it overflows the "container" but it's still showing :(.

If I simply remove the "position:absolute" it will work.

How can I hide the overflow of "div1" ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add position: relative to container div element.:

Exa:

```
  <style type="text/css">
        #container
        {
            width: 200px;
            background-color: red;
            height: 60px;
            color: white;
            position: relative;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        #div1
        {
            background-color: blue;
            position: absolute;
            top:0px;
            left:0px;
            width: 300px;
        }
    </style>

<div id="container">   
        <div id="div1">This is div1</div> 
    <div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I just thought the "position: relative" is default :-??

Comment: Default value for position is static.

Comment: If you tend to do a lot of positioning, you can set 'position: relative' as the default with ` * { position: relative; } ` at the top of your css.

Answer (score 2):

adding

```
#container { position: relative; }
```

will hide the overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Adding position absolute to an element will remove that element from the normal flow.
It will position itself absolute to the closest parent that is relatively positioned.

This is why adding "position:relative" to the "container" will achieve the desired effect.